# Entity Framework 5 (MySQL) as project (class library) on existing MVC4 solution

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I started working on my first EF project.

I would like to have EF as seperate Class Library on my Solution....

Thats how it looks:
http://shrani.si/f/3/Xh/32C70yts/ef5.jpg

I have started with existing database and import it on new Class library (as DbModel)
As well I have imported all references into MVC4 project, so I am able to work with exisiting entity clases (for DbModel.tt, - like User.cs...)

As long I use those classes (db tables) everything works... I can create new Controller... edit data, write to Db...

But when I try to write my own Model class & than try to create new Controller (MVC controller with R/W... using EF) 
I get error - Unsupported context type

Of course empty Controler can be created.

I didnt find much on DB or Model first (only really basics help), most info is on Code first aproach.

My Db should have around 100 tables on the end... if that means anything in EF at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is difficult to understand, but I assume you are looking for a little direction for using Mvc4 with the entity framework database-first.

I can't quite understand your error but your sentence "When I try to write my own model class..." makes me think of the following points:

- With database-first, you should NOT need to write entities. They are automagically generated for you from the edmx file.
- If you are writing some additional entity class using your entities, the class needs to inherit from an existing entity so that it matches something in the context.
- If you are writing a class in your Model folder to represent something purely not related to the database, your context shouldn't matter. For example, if you are writing a class called Status which represents the current application status that is not stored in your database, it shouldn't care about your contexts. Contexts are only needed for objects created by entity framework.
- You should not need to write a context object using database first. The default name of the context is `<database name>Entities`. I usually change this so it is `<database name>_entities` since my database names usually are underscored. This object should be found in the same directory/namespace as wherever you put your edmx file.
- Your error sounds like you wrote your own context. If all goes well with the edmx, you should not need to write a single line of code to get your database to connect. You will need to have a connection string in your Web.config file, but if you follow the edmx wizard as explained below, this should happen automatically.

You mentioned a class library. I do this often where I share the model logic in a common library:

- It doesn't actually matter that the models are in the Model namespace. They could come from anywhere. The above points still apply to entity framework things
- In your views, you will need to use the full namespace name of any model found in your library. For example, if you have an entity in a folder called DB in your model project called DbModel, your `@model` declaration would say that the model is `DbModel.DB.my_entity`.
- You need to have the connection string for your database in the Web.config file. It doesn't get copied from the libraries App.config file. Copy and paste is usually what I use for this, but there is probably a more clever way.

**Here is a little instruction with Entity Framework and MVC4**

First, you need to have MySQL data and entities packages installed. I usually do these through nuget just to make things easier. It sounds like you already did this, but I put this here just to be through. If you are using a separate library. use NuGet on that library. The appropriate dlls should be copied in to the bin directory when you build of both the library and the MVC project.

Next, you need to import your database. I have found the best way is to anticipate how many classes you are going to have. You said around 100 tables, so I would suggest creating a new folder in your model folder called DB or something so it doesn't get mixed up with everything else. You need to right click on this new folder and add a new item. Select ADO.Net data model. It should create an edmx file. Select the MySQL connector from the connection thing (the button says 'Change...' or something like that next to the default MSSQL connector). Enter your database information and then follow the onscreen instructions, importing your model.

You should now have a DB folder with one file in it, but when inspecting the namespace using the objectbrowser or something you should see all of your table classes.

After this, you have a few options:

- Use the entity objects directly in your views. This doesn't require any additional code
- Write ViewModels that your Controller will pass into views. These are based on the entity framework objects

Your controller shouldn't actually care what model it uses. Here is a short example of what a typical controller would look like that uses a context you created in a DB folder in your model:

```
public class HomeController : MvcController
{
    private Model.DB.my_database_context context = new Model.DB.my_database_context();

    public ActionResult ShowSomething()
    {
        return this.View(context.users.First()); //assuming you have a table called user
    }
}
```

This is incredibly unrobust (using First() throws an exception if there isn't a record in the table), but if you had a view called ShowSomething.cshtml in your Views/Home folder it should look like this:

```
@model Model.DB.a_table

@Model.user_name
```

All it would do is display the user name

Now, where it gets interesting with Models is using Web API controllers:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private Model.DB.my_database_context context = new Model.DB.my_database_context();

    public IEnumerable Get()
    {
        return context.values; //assuming you have a table called values
    }

    public value Get(string id)
    {
        return context.values.Where(v => v.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

These take your context and directly output an entity which is serialized to XML, JSON, or something else depending on certain headers in the request (Accept-Type or something like that).

Comment: great explanation and i have a question, i am into similar situation but mine is bit different, i have three separate projects, UI, DAL, SERVICE and in my project I have reference of DAL into SERVICE and I have SERVICE reference into my UI project but when i try to create scaffolding what should my data context class be? and model class? would you explain this?